# Qt QPixmap QPainter problem

Tags: qt, qpainter, qpixmap

I have a piece of code that has this lines of code:

```
int dsize = 100;
QPainter *painter;
QPixmap *img;
QLabel *l_img;

painter = new QPainter;
img = new QPixmap(dsize, dsize);

l_img = new QLabel;
l_img->setPixmap(*img);

painter->begin(img);
painter->fillRect(img->rect(), Qt::white);

QPen pen(Qt::black, 12);
painter->setPen(pen);
painter->drawLine(40, 40, 40, 100);

painter->end();
l_img->show();
```

How ever when I run the code, I don't see any white image with a black rectangle on it. In fact what I see is the title of the window written in big fonts. Nothing seems to work, I just get an image like that. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: "img = new QPixmap(dsize, dsize);" <- No need to create QPixmaps on the heap. They are implicitely shared. Just pass them by value/const ref. You probably leak memory there.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

It has this line:

```
l_img->setPixmap(*img);
```

It should be after

```
painter->end();
```

Thank you, xD.